# UserControl с параметрами в MVVM (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, usercontrol, передача-параметров

Всем привет. Вопрос от новичка.

Планирую, что в приложении в определенный момент будет создаваться некоторый экземпляр UserControl'а (не один, но это не суть важно) с передачей ему определенных данных в качестве параметра.

Дальше UserControl должен получить эти данные и создать экземпляр личной ViewModel'и, и передать данные в неё. ViewModel знает, что делать с данными.

1) Правильно ли я понимаю, что получать входные данные UserControl должен в собственном конструкторе в Code Behind? Или есть более MVVM-ное решение?

2) Насколько я понимаю, экземпляр ViewModel'и создается в XAML следующим образом:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <vm:MyControlViewModel x:Key="ControlVM"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Не могу найти описание этого синтаксиса в учебниках и мануалах, поэтому не могу понять, как здесь реализовать передачу какого-либо параметра в создаваемый экземпляр ViewModel'и.

Возможно, я мыслю совершенно не в том направлении и View Control'а не должна создавать себе экземпляр ViewModel'и? Но если создавать извне отдельно экземпляр View и отдельно экземпляр ViewModel'и, как им объяснить, что именно этот экземпляр View связывается именно с этим экземпляром ViewModel?

Comment: `UserControl должен получить эти данные и создать экземпляр личной ViewModel'` это неверно.

Comment: `Правильно ли я понимаю, что получать входные данные UserControl должен в собственном конструкторе в Code Behind?` User Control должен получать данные от вьюмодели через DataContext

Comment: `Насколько я понимаю, экземпляр ViewModel'и создается в XAML` это иногда верно только для главной вьюмодели, но в основном неверно. Идея в том, что UI генерируется по ViewModel, а не ViewModel генерируется по UI

Comment: Спасибо за быстрый отклик!

Таким образом, нужно создать извне экземпляр ViewModel'и и отдельно экземпляр View? Как объяснить View, какой именно экземпляр VIewModel'и использовать в качестве DataContext'а?

Comment: `поэтому не могу понять, как здесь реализовать передачу какого-либо параметра в создаваемый экземпляр ViewModel'и` через UI это не делается никак.

Comment: У контрола могут быть свои кастомные `DepencyProperty`, с которымы можно работать, например как с `TextBlock.Text`. А вьюмодель может с ними взаимодействовать. Так же у юзерконтрола вообще может не быть своей вьюмодели, если это не требуется. Вы же не заводите отдельную VM для каждого `TextBox`? В общем, на выходе `UserControl` - это просто `Control` со своими свойствами и особенностями. Внутренняяя логика может быть и в кодбихайнде, если это не работа с данными а логика поведения самого юзерконтрола, в любом случае кодбихайнд - это View и отвечает он за представление информации.

Comment: В моем случае хочу именно иметь отдельную ViewModel для этого UserControl'а, чтобы она хранила определенное количество данных для него.

Comment: В случае, если DP юзерконтрола напрямую к нужным свойствами прибиндить нельзя, и нужно преобразование входных/выходных данных, то нужна отдельная VM, верно.

Comment: `отдельную ViewModel для этого UserControl'а, чтобы она хранила определенное количество данных для него` у вас хвост виляет собакой, вьюмодели не хранят данные для конкретных юзерконтролов, они хранят достаточно данных, чтобы могли быть отрисованы, но они не должны знать как они будут отрисованы и кем.

Comment: @tym32167, я не говорю, что ViewModel будет хранить данные, специфичные для View. Но она знает, что какой-то Control там существует. Это ведь не противоречит идее?

Дальше - у меня,  например, будет 2 или 3 или 5 одинаковых UserControl'ов, у всех одинаковые ViewModel'и, но у всех разные данные и значит у каждого свой экземпляр ViewModel'и. 

Я мыслю как-то неверно?

Comment: VM не должна знать о сузествовании контрола. Сегодня вы её рисуете с WPF, завтра с UWP, послезавтра с Xamarin - вьюмодели это по боку по сути. Но общий посыл да, если у вас коллекция VM и вам надо это отрисовать, то у вас в UI будет какая то коллекция контролов.

Comment: Отлично, остается понять, как их связывать между собой при создании

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Показываю, как в `UserControl` можно засунуть кастомный `DepencyProperty` и прибиндить к нему свою собственную View Model.

К примеру, пусть будет 2 текстблока, один будет использовать `DepencyProperty`, другой будет пытаться взять что-то из `DataContext`, то есть из View Model. Получается вот такая разметка:

**UserControl1.xaml**

```xaml
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApp2.UserControl1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp2"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding MyText}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyVMText}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```

`DepencyProperty` живут в код-бихайнде в данном случае есть одна типа `string` и называется `MyText`.

**UserControl1.xaml.cs**

```csharp
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyText", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MyText
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(MyTextProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyTextProperty, value);
    }
}
```

Теперь ViewModel для `UserControl`.

На самом деле, VM ничего не знает про то, где и какое View будет к ней привязываться. VM просто содержит свойства и как-то их меняет, а View уже на свое усмотрение оттуда берет что-нибудь и как-нибудь это отображает. Но я как программист знаю, что мне нужна VM, обеспечивающая работу конкретного `UserControl1`, и я ее создаю и называю соответствующим образом.

**UserControlViewModel.cs**

```csharp
public class UserControlViewModel : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myVMText;

    public string MyVMText
    {
        get => _myVMText;
        set
        {
            _myVMText = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Свойство назвал по-другому, не так как DP, но можно и одинаково. Это я сделал чтобы визуально была разница.

Теперь у нас есть вьюмодель окна, где будет жить этот `UserControl1`, то есть его экземпляр, там то я и создаю эту VM как обычное свойство, реализующее `INotifyPropertyChanged`. А это все для того, чтобы если захочется переключить `UserControl.DataContext`, на другую вьюмодель в рантайме, то INPC нам поможет.

**MainViewModel.cs**

```csharp
private UserControlViewModel _userControlVM;
public UserControlViewModel UserControlVM
{
    get => _userControlVM;
    set
    {
        _userControlVM = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

// инициализирую что-нибудь в эту VM в конструкторе главной VM
public MainViewModel()
{
    UserControlVM = new UserControlViewModel { MyVMText = "Text for UserControl's VM" };
}
```

А использую это следующим образом.

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xaml
<local:UserControl1 Grid.Column="1" MyText="Text fro DepencyProperty" DataContext="{Binding UserControlVM}"/>
```

Но вы же скажете, что *`MyText` тоже можно прибиндить к чему угодно!*, и я отвечу: **да, можно**. Какой из способов доставки данных в UserControl вам больше нравится, тот и используйте. Можно вообще обойтись без кастомных `DepencyProperty` и биндиться только в VM, можно наоборот, можно смешать (но не взбалтывать!). Оба способа валидны и прекрасно подходят для MVVM.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за отзывчивость!

А если второй экземпляр этой же самой VM и этого же самого UserControl'а появятся?

Comment: @s7onoff вьюмодель - это сборник свойств. Вы же можете создать кучу текстбоксов, и прибиндить их к куче свойств, можете создать из них список, засунуть в `DataGrid`, все что угодно. Вот и здесь все так же как с обычными контролами. Задайте `Binding` для `DataContext` в нужный экземпляр VM, и дело с концом.

Comment: @s7onoff если вам помог мой ответ, пожалуйста отметьте его принятым.

Comment: @aetop я второй день пытаюсь понять, помог ли он, анализирую Ваше решение, пытаюсь увязать список одинаковых UserControl'ов с их одинаковыми ViewModel'ями. Пока не понимаю в Вашем примере, зачем нужен DependancyProperty, но, подозреваю, что дело в том, что я в принципе не очень понимаю, зачем они нужны. Читаю, разбираюсь. 

Главное, что понял - что да, конечно же, не View должен создавать VM, а кто-то создавать их обоих и связывать в этот момент. Кручусь вокруг

ControlList.Add(new Control() { DataContext = new ControlVM(Параметр_для_создания_VM) });

Пока что-то не срабатывает :)

Comment: Хотя, сейчас вот написал это всё и понял, что я опять не в той степи блуждаю и ViewModel главного окна вообще не должна создавать сама Control'ы.... VM создает новые VM, view создает новые view, но не крест накрест, иначе они начинают слишком много знать друг о друге. Окей, завтра я точно пойму, о чем Ваш пример, спасибо!)

Comment: @s7onoff `DepencyProperty` - это свойство контрола, показал я его для примера, что вот оно есть, и как его создать. Со стандартными же контролами вы через DP взаимодействуете. Я просто показал, как это сделать руками. Делать или нет - решать вам. Как говорится "копать - туда", есть от чего оттолкнуться, а дальше поиск решения и тесты.