# Как создать стиль для кнопок с разными картинками и текстом?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется следующий код:

```
<RadioButton IsChecked="True" Style="{DynamicResource menu_btn}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Height="20" Source="{StaticResource icon_shild}"/>
        <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Безопасность"/>
    </Grid>
</RadioButton>
```

Как создать универсальный стиль для кнопок, с разными иконками и текстом, и не дублировать код?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: если нужны кастомные свойства - то смотрите как создать юзерконтрол. Вот есть немного не простой [пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1255542/373567), но там есть что вам нужно. Смотреть в C# код, где написано `DependencyProperty`. Вот [еще пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137895/373567) попроще.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый очевидный способ: наследуешься и расширяешь.

Наследуешься от RadioButton:

```
public class IconRadioButton : RadioButton
{
   public IconRadioButton()
   {
      DefaultStyleKey = typeof(RadioButton);
   }

   public static readonly DependencyProperty IconSourceProperty
      = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(IconSource), typeof(ImageSource), typeof(IconRadioButton));
   
   public ImageSource IconSource
   {
      get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(IconSourceProperty); }
      set { SetValue(IconSourceProperty, value); }
   }
}
```

Соответственно, переопределяешь стиль со шаблоном.

```
<Style TargetType="local:IconRadioButton">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:IconRadioButton">
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Image Height="20" Source="{TemplateBinding IconSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               <ContentPresenter Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Используешь:

```
<local:IconRadioButton IconSource="{StaticResource icon_shild}" Content="Безопасность" />
```

Можно так же не расширять дефолтный контрол, а сделать Attached  DependencyProperty с тем же ImageSource, а в шаблоне у Image байндится на это свойство.

Создаешь присоединяемое свойство:

```
public static class AttachedImageSource
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty
      = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ImageSource", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AttachedImageSource));

   public static void SetImageSource(DependencyObject element, ImageSource value)
   {
      element.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value);
   }

   public static ImageSource GetImageSource(DependencyObject element)
   {
      return (ImageSource)element.GetValue(ImageSourceProperty);
   }
}
```

Переопределяешь стиль RadioButton:

```
<Style TargetType="RadioButton" x:Key="RadioButtonIcon">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
            <Grid>
               <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
               </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <Image Height="20" Source="{TemplateBinding local:AttachedImageSource.ImageSource}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
               <ContentPresenter Margin="5,0,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
</Style>
```

Используешь:

```
<RadioButton local:AttachedImageSource.ImageSource="{StaticResource icon_shild}" Content="Безопасность" Style="{StaticResource RadioButtonIcon}" />
```

Ну или делать UserControl, хотя по сути это тоже самое будет: свойство, шаблон и байндинг.

Всякие мелочи:

- ContentPresenter можно спокойно заменить на TextBlock, если только текст и нужен.
- Image можно заменить на любое другое содержимое и вместо ImageSource IconSource использовать что душе угодно.
- Ещё в стилях обычно всякие другие свойства байдятся, типа VerticalContentAlignment, но это уже отдельная тема для разговора.
- Не знаю зачем тебе RadioButton, тут и Button подошла бы, но если тебе ещё при изменении состояния (IsChecked) нужно менять, например, иконку, то тут уже триггеры нужны. И, например, ещё одно свойство, если картинка меняется. Но это опять же отдельная тема.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ!