# Как получить объект из ресурса в WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я хотел поступить по умному, но что-то зашел в тупик. У меня есть некоторый массив чисел, каждое из которых я бы хотел менять в диалоговом окне (но это не суть).

Ниже представлены ресурсы (точнее ресурс) проекта, это некоторый заготовленный элемент, который помещается в StackPanel в окне. Он содержит в себе метку и текстовое поле.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,10" Height="22" x:Key="ListOutputElem" x:Shared="false">
        <Grid Width="200">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Выход 0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window.Resources>
```

Чтобы заполнить StackPanel этими элементами, я в конструкторе получаю ресурс и размещаю его в нужном элементе столько раз сколько нужно. То есть у меня есть объект этого участка кода, который я могу размещать где угодно.

Но главное, мне нужно взять и связать текстовые поля и источниками данных. Конечно можно было использовать Binding в xaml, но тогда нужно как-то указать индекс, что наверняка можно, но хочется делаться это не в xaml.

Так вот, как я сказал, я получаю элемент StackPanel при помощи FindResource, но я не могу получить доступ к тем элементам которые внутри его. Задание имени текстовому полю и получение его при помощи FindName, почему-то не возвращают этот элемент.

Еще отмечу, что да я могу просто конструировать вот этот элемент в коде и как угодно задавать привязки, но хочется все же разметку оставить в xaml.

Comment: Вы делаете совершенно не то и не так. То, что вы хотите - зовется `UserControl`, тыкнули ПКМ по проекту - добавить - пользовательский элемент управления, далее задали ему вид нужный, а в коде `<namespace:MyUserControl SomeProperty = "Привет мир!"/>`, все, без всяких ресурсов и прочего. Далее ` я в конструкторе получаю ресурс и размещаю его в нужном элементе столько раз сколько нужно` - этого **вообще не должно быть в WPF**, ведь WPF это про то, как вы привязываете UI к данным, вы не должны вообще хотеть что либо в C# делать с контролами, не должно быть `myTextBox.Text = ".."`.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137895/373567, плюс совет: используйте `TextBlock` вместо `Label`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ  Спасибо, не очень просто хотел добавлять UserControl, но видимо через ресурсы точно не стоит делать. 

Можно еще тогда краткий вопрос, в продолжение темы, что WPF это про привязывание данных?  Правильно ли использовать конструктор, для добавления этих контроллов, так как количество элементов в массиве может быть разное?

Comment: Нет. Повторю, в C# коде вы **не должны** хотеть обращаться к UI. Забудьте про `x:Name` в XAML, вот пишите проект так, будто их нету. Представьте, что у вас консольный проект, вот нету UI, как вы там решите свою задачу? Наверно сделаете класс, в котором будет коллекция объектов, методы по добавлению/редактированию/удалению, правильно? Ну так в WPF также, вот прям в точности также (почти). У вас должен быть проект таким, чтоб когда вы удаляли контрол в XAML, он не падал с ошибками. Коллекция? Пожалуйста `<ItemsControl ItemsSource = "{Binding Items}">...</ItemsControl>`. Клик? `ICommand`. и др.

Comment: Для коллекций есть `<ItemsControl/>`, ложите его в XAML, привязывайте к любой коллекции и готово. Для того чтобы разметить элемент, достаточно определить ему `<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>`, там же в XAML. Примеров полинтернета. Панель для размещения можно тоже ему любую задать. По умолчанию там вертикальная `<StackPanel>`, надо горизонтальную - легко `<ItemsControl.ItemsPanel><ItemsPanelTemplate><StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/></ItemsPanelTemplate></ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>`. То есть берете свой грид с двумя колонками, кладете в ItemTemplate, и готово. 0 строк на C#.

Comment: @aepot это именно то, что я искал) Можете ли добавить его в качестве ответа на вопрос?