# Как передать в user control текущий экземпляр класса

Tags: c#, wpf

Как передать в user control текущий экземпляр, чтобы его использовать для привязки внутри user control (ItemCard).

Строчка `<customcontrols:ItemCard></customcontrols:ItemCard>` Это и есть user control (ItemCard)

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
using Organaizer.MVVM.Model;
using Organaizer.MVVM.View;
using Organaizer.MVVM.ViewModel.Base;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Organaizer.MVVM.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
       
        private ObservableCollection<ItemInfoCard> _itemInfoCards = new ObservableCollection<ItemInfoCard>() {
            new ItemInfoCard(E_CategoryGroup.dir, false),
            new ItemInfoCard(E_CategoryGroup.exe, false)
        };
        public IEnumerable<ItemInfoCard> ItemInfoCards
        {
            get => _categoryGroup==E_CategoryGroup.favorite? _itemInfoCards.Where(item => item.IsFavorite == true) : _itemInfoCards.Where(item => item.CategoryGroup == _categoryGroup);
        }
        public void Initialize()
        {
            _itemInfoCards.Add(new ItemInfoCard(E_CategoryGroup.exe, true));
        }

        #region Commands

        private ICommand _cmdSelectedGroup;
        public ICommand CmdSelectedGroup => _cmdSelectedGroup = new RelayCommand<string>(SelectedGroup);
        private void SelectedGroup(string value)
        {
            _categoryGroup = (E_CategoryGroup) Enum.Parse(typeof(E_CategoryGroup), value);
            RisePropertyChanged(nameof(ItemInfoCards));
        }


        private ICommand _cmdAddElement;
        public ICommand CmdAddElement => _cmdAddElement = new RelayCommand(AddElement);
        private void AddElement(object item)
        {
            SelectAddType vm = new SelectAddType(this);
            vm.Show();
        }


        private ICommand _cmdSelectFavorite;
        public ICommand CmdSelectFavorite => _cmdSelectFavorite = new RelayCommand<bool>(SelectFavorite);
        private void SelectFavorite(bool value)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(value.ToString());
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

---

**MainWindows.xaml**

```
            ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" >
                <ItemsControl Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemInfoCards}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapPanel Margin="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <customcontrols:ItemCard></customcontrols:ItemCard>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                </ItemsControl>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

---

**ItemCard.xaml.cs**

```
namespace Organaizer.UserControls
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для ItemCard.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class ItemCard : UserControl
    {
        public ItemCard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ItemCard]

Comment: DataContext же. Он наследуется, поэтому скорее всего там уже все передано как надо. А вообще есть DependencyProperty https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1441493/373567 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1137895/373567

Comment: Что делает `ItemCard`? Если это контрол по типу `TextBox`, то он не должен знать вообще чего-либо про данные, он должен иметь конкретный вид, иметь конкретные свойства (свои), а снаружи уже этим свойствам задаются значения (`<...:ItemCard Title = "Заголовок" Name = "Вася" Age = "123" />`). Если это а-ля страница, со своим видом, данными и прочим, то там идет свое разделение на слои (View и VM), которые связываются через `DataContext`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ItemCard достаточно много всего делает. Приложил скриншот на что он похож. Код громоздкий там конечно. Если нужно приложу

Comment: Если делает много - значит он выполняет не свою ответственность, разделите на мелкие контролы. А так, ну сделайте свойства зависимости и привяжите их. Например, я вижу на скрине выше кнопку запуска, кнопку редактирования, кнопку избранного и еще наверно парочка команд в троеточие, наверно может и картинка есть, а не просто черный фон) Вот у вас получается несколько `DependencyProperty` с типом `ICommand` для всех кликов, а использование просто `<uc:ItemCard Start = "{Binding ItemStartCommand}" .... />`, как бы стандартные контролы)

Comment: То есть, вы не объект пытайтесь сунуть туда, на основе которого контрол все сделает, а наоборот, сделайте универсальный контрол, с конкретным дизайном, у которого есть конкретные свойства, он не должен знать ничего про данные. А данные уже привязываете к каждому свойству контрола свои.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Да вы правы что там не так много команд и можно забиндить через DependencyProperty. Просто хотелось узнать, можно как то компактно это сделать ? Тогда придется передавать новую VM ?

Comment: Контролы, это View слой, а если вы делаете все по правилам MVVM, то View не должен знать ничего про другие слои, ему должно быть без разницы какой объект идет на вход. Вот возьмите любой стандартный контрол, он на вход принимает интерфейс? Может конкретный класс? Да вроде нет. Каждый контрол имеет у себя конкретные свойства, которые созданы для выполнения конкретных его задач, а вы уже, как пользователь этих контролов, задаете им конкретные значения. 3-5 DependencyProperty это не так много, чтоб думать о "компактности", подумайте лучше о практичности, может этот контрол пригодится вам где еще.

Comment: Ну а если нужна компактность, то тогда сразу внутри контрола задавайте привязки к нужным свойствам и тупо задавайте ему `DataContext` на класс, который содержит эти все свойства, будет вам просто `<control DataContext = "{Binding Item}"/>`, компактно? Да вроде да. Но что с практичностью, переиспользованием, и так далее? Как понимаете, вы гвоздями все внутри контрола забиваете, что не всегда есть хорошо. Поэтому думайте как лучше поступить именно в вашем случае.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Подскажите а как команду забиндить с текущей viewModel ? Так не получается, пишет Свойство MainViewModel не найдено для объекта типа ItemInfoCard.

`<customcontrols:ItemCard IsFavorite="{Binding IsFavorite}" FavoriteCommand="{Binding MainViewModel/CmdSelectFavorite}"></customcontrols:ItemCard>`

Comment: я так полагаю что так FavoriteCommand="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.CmdSelectFavorite }

Comment: В коллекции у каждого элемента свой `DataContext`, ну а если нужен контекст родителя, то да, через `FindAncestor` находится родитель, и у него берется уже свойство.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот только не могу понять. У меня есть комманда IsFavorite. Как я могу поменять значение?

Comment: @АндрейReyz А почему это команда, а не `bool` переменная? Если это всеж `bool` и не обновляется, то попробуйте задать мод привязки на `TwoWay` (можете прям у [DependencyProperty](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7268092/6808809)).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну а свойство slectedItemInfoCard нужно будет создавать, можно как то сразу передать в ICommand выбранный обьект ?

Comment: @АндрейReyz Для передачи чего-либо в команду существуют ее параметры (свойство `CommandParameter`).